# \.... already defined. I can't found my mistake

Tags: errors, compiling, undefined

I can't find my mistake. That TeX file has been working for about half a year. But today it does not work. Where is my mistake?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Зураг
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is all of this Russian? If so why is the last and active language given to babel mongolian? Additionally don't use `\text` like this, it does not do what you think. Your use seems to be named indices, these should be typeset upright, for example `\textrm`, but that is not always what text does.

Comment: @daleif Mongolian can be written in traditional Mongolian script or Cyrillic. It appears that this document uses Cyrillic. A quick look at the `mongolian-babel` documentation suggests `\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}` is intended for Cyrillic Mongolian. So that would check out.

Comment: More minimal example for the issue at https://gist.github.com/moewew/3cfb8bf10213811ab6acdce1ae5d536d

Comment: As far as I can see this is a clash between `babel-russian` and `mongolian-babel`. Both want to redefine commands like `\sh`. `mongolian-babel` uses `\def`. But when `amsmath` is loaded `babel-russian` uses `\DeclareMathOperator`, which only works if the command is undefined and throws the error we are getting if the macro is already defined. If you only need Mongolian in your document, you can drop the `russian` option for `babel` and things will just work. But if you need Russian, another workaround is needed ...

Answer (score 7):

In `mongolian.ldf` we find

```
\def\sh{\mathop{\operator@font sh}\nolimits}
[...]
```

and in `russianb.ldf` we find

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}
  {%
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sh}{sh}%\MakeRobust\sh
    [...]
  }{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\sh{\mathop{\operator@font sh}\nolimits}%\MakeRobust\sh%
    [...]
  }%
  \let\text@th\th
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\th}{\TextOrMath{\text@th}{\math@th}}
}
```

where `[...]` stands for similar lines about the other math operators.

Since you're loading `mongolian` as the main language, `russianb.ldf` is loaded after `mongolian.ldf`. And `\DeclareMathOperator{\sh}{sh}` will throw an error if `\sh` is already defined.

In my opinion both language definition files are at fault, because they both assume that those commands are undefined. Note that `russianb.ldf` seems aware of the fact that `\th` already has a definition.

The code in `russianb.ldf` is much better than the corresponding code in `mongolian.ldf` and they should be aligned, but with added checks so no conflict can arise.

If you don't need Russian, don't load the language. Otherwise, here's a workaround

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[base]{babel}
\AfterBabelLanguage{mongolian}{%
  \let\sh\relax\let\ch\relax\let\tg\relax
  \let\arctg\relax\let\arcctg\relax
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\th\csname ltx@th\endcsname
  \let\ctg\relax\let\cth\relax\let\cosec\relax
}
\usepackage[russian,mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Зураг

$\sh x$

\end{document}
```

With `\AfterBabelLanguage` we neutralize the weak definitions done by `mongolian.ldf` and the document will use the more robust `russianb.ldf` ones.